# Android app changes on device language change

Tags: java, android

i wrote an android application 
but when the device language changes to Persian
all of the elements in app change their gravity 
how can i avoid it ?

Comment: "how can i avoid it" - do not set device language to Persian. Just kidding - I guess you'll have to handle "right-to-left" mode. See http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: Persian is a language which you read from right to left. That behaviour is correct and you shouldn't override it.

Answer (score 1):

i just had to put this in android manifest

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

Comment: Not the best way to do it.